# how to put selection in first row after sorting in nat table?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, nattable

how to put selection in first row after sorting in nat table, I'm using SortHeaderLayer for sorting ..... thanks in advance

```
 SortHeaderLayer<Mapping> sortHeaderLayer =new SortHeaderLayer<Mapping>(columnHeaderLayer, new GlazedListsSortModel<Mapping>(sortedList,columnAccessor,configRegistry, columnHeaderDataLayer), false);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by registering `ILayerListener`. The only thing to keep in mind is that the `SortColumnEvent` is fired first and afterwards the `GlazedListsEventLayer` fires a `RowStructuralRefreshEvent` to trigger repainting. This will remove the selection when not using the `RowSelectionModel`. Therefore the listeners need to be designed in a reactive way.

```
    // an ILayerListener that performs a selection after a refresh and 
    // unregisters itself afterwards
    ILayerListener sortListener = new ILayerListener() {

        @Override
        public void handleLayerEvent(ILayerEvent event) {
            if (event instanceof RowStructuralRefreshEvent) {
                natTable.doCommand(new SelectRowsCommand(natTable,
                        1, 1, false, false));
                natTable.removeLayerListener(this);
            }
        }
    };

    // register an ILayerListener that registers the above listener
    // on a SortColumnEvent
    natTable.addLayerListener(new ILayerListener() {

        @Override
        public void handleLayerEvent(ILayerEvent event) {
            if (event instanceof SortColumnEvent) {
                natTable.addLayerListener(sortListener);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ... one more thing i need to know ....that how can we place a selected row in first position of table ...after sorting ....

Comment: In that case you need to change the sort algorithm or work with the RowReorderLayer. Nothing to explain in short for free.